# How to match a folder name and use it in an if condition using grep in bash?

Tags: bash, grep

```
for d in */ ; do
    cd $d
    NUM = $(echo ${PWD##*/} | grep -q "*abc*");
    if [[ "$NUM" -ne "0" ]]; then
        pwd
    fi
    cd ..
done
```

Here I'm trying to match a folder name to some substring 'abc' in the name of the folder and check if the output of the grep is not 0. But it gives me an error which reads that `NUM: command not found`

---

An error was addressed in comments.
`NUM = $(echo ${PWD##*/} | grep -q "*abc*");` should be `NUM=$(echo ${PWD##*/} | grep -q "*abc*");`.

---

To clarify, the core problem would be **to be able to match current directory name to a pattern.**

Comment: @PS still the same.

Comment: `NUM=$(...` - without spaces

Comment: @jm666 No errors now. But purpose isn't solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably simply the code to just

```
if grep -q "*abc*" <<< "${PWD##*/}" 2>/dev/null; then
   echo "$PWD"
   # Your rest of the code goes here
fi
```

You can use the exit code of the `grep` directly in a if-conditional without using a temporary variable here (`$NUM` here). The condition will pass if `grep` was able to find a match. The here-string `<<<`, will pass the input to `grep` similar to `echo` with a pipeline. The part `2>/dev/null` is to just suppress any errors (`stderr - file descriptor 2`) *if* `grep` throws!

---

As an additional requirement asked by OP, to negate the conditional check just do

```
if ! grep -q "*abc*" <<< "${PWD##*/}" 2>/dev/null; then
```

Comment: Could you explain the answer?

Comment: What does 2>/dev/null do? I suppose it suppresses some kind of output?

Comment: `*abc*` I want a folder having substring abc @jm666

Comment: What if I want to negate the result here? @Inian

Comment: @jm666: I suppose to use the _glob_ match, you need to enabled extended regexp, `-E`

Comment: @Inian This helped. Thanks.

Comment: @jm666 It is `abc`. Not `*abc*`. I just came to know that grep searched entire line and shows entire line it even a substring matches.